# Check if an array of object has an object having a key with a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

By using `underscore` or `jQuery` is there a better way to check if an array of object `[{id: 1, name: 'some name'}, {id: 2, name: 'other name'}]` contains a specific attribute value?

Here is my way:

```
_.filter([{id: 1}, {id: 2}], 
      function(obj){ return obj.id === 3 }).length === 1; // false

_.filter([{id: 1}, {id: 2}], 
      function(obj){ return obj.id === 2 }).length === 1; // true
```

Comment: I did it in this way too. Couldn't find a better method.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the object itself, but only to check whether it is in your list:

```
_.contains(_.pluck([{id: 1}, {id: 2}], 'id'), 1) // => true
```

the docs: [_.pluck()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck),
[_.contains()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#contains)